# delete data from linked list

Tags: c++

I'm trying to delete from a linked list. But it doesn't seems to be working if i try to delete the first element.

```
if (found)
{
    if (prev == NULL)
    {
        prev = head;
        prev -> next = curr -> next;
        delete curr;
    }
    else
    {
        prev -> next = curr -> next;
        delete curr;
    }
}

return found;
```

The findNode functions works if i were to delete from somewhere in the middle or from the tail. But i figured out that if i delete from the tail, i've have to set the next to NULL, am i right?

Comment: Can you show the `findNode` function? Most important is how you pass (and set) the `prev` and `curr` arguments.

Comment: i you have a header node, why doesn't then `prev` point to to that header node already after a successful search for first node

Comment: When showing a function, please show the _complete_ function, including the function header.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is *probably* that you don't actually change the `head` to point to the new head of the list. You have to change the `head`:

```
if (prev == NULL)
{
    head = head->next;  // Set `head` to point to the next node, i.e. the new `head`
    delete curr;
}
```

Comment: gosh what a dumb mistake i did there. thanks for the help guys! solved. i changed  prev = head; prev -> next = curr -> next; to head = curr -> next;

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `findNode` is correct and sets `prev` to the node before `curr` (might want to consider a doubly linked list) then

```
   if (prev == NULL)
   {
      prev = head;
      prev -> next = curr -> next;
      delete curr;
   }
```

is incorrect. Since when `prev` is NULL it is the head node that is the one found.

So the code should be

```
   if (prev == NULL)
   {
      head = head->next;
      delete curr;
   }
```